# How can one visualize a real, symmetric $3 \times 3$ tensor with zero trace?

Tags: tensor-calculus, mathematics, geometry, trace

I am looking for the simplest way to visualize a **real**, **symmetric** **3x3** tensor than has vanishing trace. (All entries are real numbers.)

It cannot be an ellipsoid, because an ellipsoid has three positive eigenvalues, and thus its trace is positive, and not vanishing.

Is there something equally simple for the case of zero trace?
(Zero trace means that the sum of all diagonal elements is zero.)

P.S. Also asked, without success, in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4577043

Comment: Hermitian?......

Comment: No symmetric, real numbers. Good point, I will add this.

Comment: In essence, any such matrix is a sum of a positive matrix and a multiple of the identity. Thus, you can think of it as, e.g., an ellipse shifted away from the origin. The question is whether this interpretation makes any sense - but this depends on your application.

Comment: A particular kind of hyperboloid? The state space of a spin $2$ particle? The space of $d$ orbitals?

Comment: Such matrices arise as the Hessian matrices ($\partial_i\partial_j f$) of solutions $f$ of Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 f = \partial_i\partial_i f= 0$. These matrices have 5 unique elements. It is possible that these 5 elements are related to the $\ell=2$ terms in the spherical harmonic expansion of $f$. If so, the sum of those spherical harmonics (which maps onto the 5 independent components of your matrix) could be visualized on a sphere or using one of the visualization techniques shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Polar_Plots.

Comment: My last comment is a comment rather than an answer because I'm not exactly sure of the relationship between the 5 components of the matrix and the five $\ell=0$ spherical harmonic expansion coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 1 point of view. The Lie group $G=O(3)$ of [orthogonal transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) in 3D acts via [similarity transformation/conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) on the 5-dimensional subspace $V$ of traceless symmetric $3\times 3$ real matrices.

This may be identified with a change of the tensor components under a change of orthonormal basis.

In fact $V$ furnishes an [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) spin-2 representation. E.g. $V$ can be decomposed into eigenspaces for the angular momentum $L_z$.

Answer (score 0):

I can only come up with a visualization for a 3×3 skew-symmetric matrix.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Corresponds to a line through the origin along the $(a,b,c)$ vector since

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = t\, \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$$

trivially solves the above equation.

To make the line go though a specific point $(u,v,w)$ not at the origin, then use the equation

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b w - c v \\ c u - a w \\ a v - b u \end{bmatrix} $$

---

So I tried to find a nifty solution to the 3×3 symmetric matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & c & b \\ c & 0 & a \\ b & a & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

for $(x,y,z)$ with a geometric interpretation and did find anything. Only $(x,y,z)=0$ is a solution which isn't helpful.

---

Moving into homogeneous coordinates with $(x,y,z,1)$ you can define a surface with

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^\intercal \begin{bmatrix}
0 & c & b & 0 \\ c & 0 & a & 0  \\ b & a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

produces a surface with equation

$$ a (y z) + b ( x z ) + c ( x y ) = \tfrac{1}{2} $$

this is a 3D hyperbolic surface since the $z=0$ slice is the curve $x y = \tfrac{1}{2 c}$

Comment: The trace should be zero, but not each entry in the diagonal...

Comment: @KlausK the 3×3 matrix has trace zero, but you can embed this matrix into a 4×4 matrix for visualization purposes , just as if you did so with a diagonal 3×3 matrix you would visualize it with a 3D ellipsoid.